# Printed/Online List of All Major Sugyas

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-bavli

I would like to see a printed or an online list of major sugyas from the Bavli - obviously, together with references (so that I can look them up for myself), but ideally also with a little bit of information about each one. Does such a thing exists? My intention is to use it as an index (say, to find every instance in which a particular concept or din is discussed), but to also use it as a guide as to which sugyas are found in individual masekhtas, and to maybe get a sense as to the various conceptual ways in which each masekhta is linked to every other.

Comment: I am not sure that Reb Chaim Shmuelevitz would have agreed with the concept of a "major" *sugyah* (*michlal de'ika* minor).

Comment: You should check out the [HaMafteach](https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=10694&strReferer=search&PPGR=0) as well.

Comment: the closest sefer to what your describing (that I know of) would be כולל מאמרים ופסגמים (3 volume green set)

Comment: How would you define "major"?

Comment: ספר כסף נבחר. תמצא אותו בהיפרובוקס